# Linux X-Session Script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rdp

Okay, I have a strange issue. I am trying to create an X-Session script which will automatically log into a remmina remote desktop, and then return to the login screen when the remote desktop is disconnected. Here is the script that the x-session calls:

```
#! /bin/bash

gnome-wm &
sleep 10
exec remmina -c /home/user/.remmina/opi.remmina;
logout
```

This correctly connects to the requested remote desktop, but when the session is logged out nothing happens, the screen freezes, the mouse works but nothing is active. If I adjust the script to call Firefox instead like so:

```
#! /bin/bash

gnome-wm &
sleep 10
exec firefox;
logout
```

It works as expected. Firefox loads, and when closed, you are returned to the login screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `exec` as it makes `firefox` take over of your script:

`exec firefox`

Must just be:

`firefox`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I updated my script, but it did not change the behavior.  The script still works as expected with Firefox, loads the browser, and then returns to login when the browser is closed.  But with Remmina the window just freezes when the session is disconnected.